# Bash while loop with remote grep containing local $variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, while-loop

I would like to achieve the following

- get user input from `read nodename`
- ssh to remote host and `grep -w /path/to/file $nodename`
- if $nodename is found `echo "Sorry, hostname already exists, please try again"`
- get user input for a new $nodename
- repeat until $nodename is unique

What I have

```
echo "Please enter a node name"
read nodename

while ssh remotehost.example.com "grep -w '$nodename' /path/to/file"  
            do
                   echo "Sorry, node name already exists, please try again"
                   read nodename
    done
```

If i run `ssh remotehost.example.com "grep -w '$node' /path/to/file"` at the promt, it returns the correct answer.  However, when run in the above while loop,everything in the remote file gets printed to stdout and the answer is always to ask for a new nodename.

What do I need to change to make `ssh remotehost.example.com "grep -w '$node' /path/to/file"`work in a while loop?

Comment: Add an `if ` condition inside the loop to check for the grep output, then print the result/read the nodename again.

Comment: As an optimization, look into connection multiplexing so that each instance of `ssh` does not have to authenticate. (You would run `ssh` once, in the background, before the loop, then each instance in the loop would share the pre-established connection.)

Comment: This should be fine. However, you're confusing `$node` and `$nodename` in the description. Is there any chance you did that in the script too? This would explain why it's printing everything every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try next:

```
echo "Please enter a node name"
read nodename

while true
do
    ssh example.com "grep -q ${nodename} /path/to/file"
    status="${?}"
    if [[ ${status} -eq 0 ]]
    then
        echo "Sorry, node name already exists, please try again"
        read nodename
    else break
    fi
done
```

---

- `grep -q ...` - Quiet; do not write anything to standard output.  Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found, even if an error was detected.
- `status="${?}"` - exit status of a remote command executed via ssh command
- check `status` of remote command and do a required logic
- profit

Comment: Excellent, this worked exactly as I'd hoped. Thanks!